# How to send or update a notification silently in Android 14

Tags: android, notifications

I have recently upgraded my app to SDK v34 (Android 14) and have run into issues with notifications. I found that Android 14 no longer honors setOngoing (it can still be swiped away), but also, now my notifications are not silent. setSound(null) seems to be ignored as well. They vibrate or sound every time. Here is my Notification builder:

```
 String sChannelId = "notifyme_channel";
      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, sChannelId)
              .setSmallIcon(iconResource)
              .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
              .setContentText("Profile: " + AppInit.sCurActiveAlert + ", Alarm: " + AppInit.sNextAlarm)
              .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                      .bigText("Profile: " + AppInit.sCurActiveAlert + "\nNext Check: " +
                              AppInit.sNextScheduledProfileCheck + "\nNext Alarm: " + AppInit.sNextAlarm))
              .setTicker("Loading " + context.getString(R.string.app_name) + " notification...")
              .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
              .setOngoing(true)
              .setSound(null)
              .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

There is no need for the notification banner or icon to make a sound or vibrate, it's just updating the state of the app for the user to see at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

Lol

```
.setSilent(true).
```

I only found this from looking through builder parameters and found mSilent! Not sure how I missed this but anyway.